# Arduino not connecting to computer after working before

Tags: macos, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I bought my Arduino Uno R3 a few months ago.  It's been working like a charm since then, but today, it stopped interfacing with my computer.  Let me be more specific.  I have a 2013 Macbook Pro Retina with OS X 10.9 (Mavericks).  It has the latest Arduino IDE installed.

I was using it today and after uploading a simple sketch (it worked for a little while) my Mac stopped recognizing it, and since, I haven't been able to access it.  The LED connected to Pin 13 stays on 100% of the time.  The RX/TX LEDs don't flash, but the main functions of my sketch (other than the serial functions).

Have I screwed my Arduino's Serial chip?  What can I do?  I am only 15, so another $30 is a little bit too much to spend to get another one.... :)

Thanks!!

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I have tried my other Windows computer, and another cable, just to rule out those possibilities.

Comment: what error do you have? avrdude() not responding?

Comment: Check your device manager. Sometimes It's virtual serial port name can be changed. In windows it becomes "COM4" from "COM3". So first of all you need to check if your computer can see serial port.

Comment: I am seeing no real errors other than the following:

Comment: I am seeing no real errors other than it asks to select a port.  It isn't a member of the list. (Sorry about the other comment)

Comment: @Zgrknr I tried that... it doesn't show up on either computer (Mac or Windows) in the port viewer.

Comment: @jusbour  Just FYI.  There is now a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com .  Ask (make a flag) the mode to migrate your question, if you think that your question would work better over there.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very common issue with Arduino. I used to face that problem all the time while using Arduino. Though I never really found a solution for this, the problem did go away after sometime. Did you try resetting the uC using the reset button on the board, or restarting the IDE or your system if neither worked?

Make sure you have chosen the right COM port. On a windows system you can do this by going to device manager and look for the ports tab under it.